# How do i make AllDaySlot not overlap my popup?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar

i made a div popup that appears when you want to make an event.
The popup works great on the "Month" view of fullcalendar,but on the "Week" and "Day" view,the allDaySlot overlap the div and make it impossible to click on the "X" span
I don't know why it's only the AllDaySlot that have a problem with that since everything else works
Any idea?
Here is the most important part of the code of my div popup(sorry if the code can be not very optimized,i'm still learning)

```
<div id="popupjs" class="popup">
        <div class="contenu-popup" id="contenupopup">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>

            ...a lot of content...

        </div>
    </div>
```

```
.popup {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.contenu-popup {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10% auto;
    height: 60%;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```
select: function(info) {
            ...i removed some codes so you can focus on the essentials...
            var popup = document.getElementById("popupjs");
            var contenupopup = document.getElementById("contenupopup");
            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];
            var body = document.getElementById("body");
            if (calendar.view.type === "dayGridMonth") {
                var allDays = true;
            } else
                {
                    var allDays = false;
                }


            popup.style.display = "block";
            contenupopup.style.height = "34%";
            body.style.overflow = "hidden";

            calendar.unselect();


            span.onclick = function() {
                popup.style.display = "none";
                body.style.overflow = "auto";
            }
```

Here's a screenshot so you can visualize the problem.
[image]
Thanks.

Comment: You can try to provide a better reproducible code so that we can debug the styling.

Comment: you mean a "test" page with only the code for the popup?

Comment: Why don't you just increase the z-index of the popup?

Comment: I don't know how i didnt see this solution,i was so focused on FullCalendar i didnt think of that.Thanks for making my head reboot!